# jQuery buttonset not reflecting update

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a few radio buttonsets using jQuery UI and jQuery 1.6+

When a certain radio is checked 'yes' another radio is forced to be checked also.

```
<input type="radio" name="111" class="set111a" id="111a" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="111" class="set111b" id="111b" value="0" checked="checked" />

<input type="radio" name="112" class="set112a" id="112a" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="112" class="set112b" id="112b" value="0" checked="checked" />
```

Here is the jQuery code I'm using to attempt to force the other radio to check.

```
$("#112a").change(function() {
    if ($("#112a").is(":checked")) {
        $('#111a').prop("checked",true);
        $("#111b").prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

It does work but only when the data is checked (via submitting the form). It's shows that if 112 is 1, then 111 is 1. But, the issues is this: the actually visual part of the '111' button still shows that it is set to "NO" (or a value of 0).

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me. I might suggest disabling the invalid radio button `#111b` if `#111a` is required, otherwise they might just override your manual forcing. Also, you only get the change event to fire on a radio button when that radio button is actually being turned on, so you might want a broader selector.

```
$("input").change(function()
{
  if ($("#112a").is(":checked"))
  {
      $('#111a').prop("checked",true);
      $('#111b').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $("#111b").prop("checked",false);
  }
  else
  {
      $('#111b').attr('disabled', null);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, is this you want to do

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="111" class="set111a" id="111a" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="111" class="set111b" id="111b" value="0" checked="checked" />

<input type="radio" name="112" class="set112a" id="112a" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="112" class="set112b" id="112b" value="0" checked="checked" />

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click after change"/>
```

**JS**

```
$("#112a").change(function() {
    if ($("#112a").is(":checked")) {
        $('#111a').click();
    }
});

$("#btn").click(function() {
    alert($("#111a").is(":checked"));
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/4f2FY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call refresh on the buttonset so the ui updates

```
$("#radio").buttonset(); // <-- whatever element you are wrapping the radio buttons in
$("#112a").change(function() {
    if ($("#112a").is(":checked")) {
        $('#111a').prop("checked",true);
        $("#111b").prop("checked",false);
    }
  $("#radio").buttonset('refresh'); // <-- refresh the buttonset
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kBKUB/)

Here's a link to the [button api](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/)